# How do a rollback in Sql Alchemy (using flask)?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm processing a medium file (20k rows) from a csv to the database (mysql), and I would like to do rollback (if there is a error). I have the files:

```
  def processBlock(self, chunk):
   
    try:
      user = UserReposity()
      list_users = user.create(chunk)

      #other repositories

    except Exception as e:
      session.rollback()
```

My Repository is:

```
from api.models.doctor import User
from api.utils.database import db

class UserReposity:

  def create(self, list):


    user_object_list = []
    for line in list:

      user = User(
                      USER_FIRST_NAME      =   line['First Name'],
                      USER_LAST_NAME       =   line['Last Name']
                    )

      user_object_list.append(user)


      db.session.bulk_save_objects(user_object_list, return_defaults=True)
    db.session.commit()
```

But it is not working, any idea please?

I tried to use:
`session.rollback()`

but doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to place the try/except and the rollback in the repository instead of the `processBlock` function ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i should use the line:

```
 db.session.flush()
```

Then i should do all my operations, finally if all my transactions are Ok, i should send the commit, or if it fails, i should send the rollback.